# Stale results from QueryBuilder?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to debug a very strange issue with Doctrine's QueryBuilder. What I'm doing looks roughly like this:

```
$entity->setDeleted(true);
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush(entity);

//the filter basically appends 'deleted = 0' to the query
$em->getFilters()->enable('softdelete');
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
   ->from($entity_class, 'c')
   ->where('c.id = ?0')
   ->setParameter(0, $entity->getId())
   ->select("COUNT(c)");
$result = intval($qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult());
```

What I would expect to happen is of course that $result is zero, but instead, I get 1. If I check the database manually, the value seems to be written correctly (i.e. it says "1", not "0")

So I tried to enable Doctrine's SQLEchoLogger to see what kind of statements are executed, and the weird thing is: When the logger is enabled, the result is zero as expected. So I was wondering: How could I debug this problem, and what could it be? The DB driver is pdo_mysql (with MyISAM tables), and as far as I can tell, I have no caching enabled.

Comment: Hi, 

Could you tail your sql slow query log and see if that tells you the exact query you are building.

Comment: I tried, but can't seem to get anything useful out of it. But I don't think it is MySQL related, I managed to reproduce the same problem with the pdo_sqlite backend